# Share announcement between internal-external users in Comunnities

Tags: community, chatter, customer-community, chatter-groups, custom-notification

this is the first time I ask something in here. So I will try to explain as best as I can

**User Case**

There's a requirement in which the internal users need to post announcements that the external users who log in the communities portal can see

**Approaches tried**

1. Chatter groups: the problem is that you can't use an internal chatter group to add as a component to the community portal
2. Custom notification: We could achieve this, and it worked when the internal user post a comment in an internal chatter group, the users in the community portal have seen the notification. The constraint with this approach, is that the notifications have a limit of characters and when the community users click on it, An error will be throwed.

**Question**

Do you have any other idea to meet the requirement or in other case, improve the approaches tried at the moment?

Any additional info you need, please let me know. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Have you considered letting the internal users login to the community?  You can give community access to internal users and then they can post to the community groups.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, we have considered grant access to internal user, but we're still trying to find a different solution